# Implement Realtime Barcode Scanner on Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime using ZXing and MFT

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, barcode, zxing

I'm working on a Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime shopping application which needs barcode scanner feature. I'm using the ZXing lib, which is fine. My problem isn't about decoding the picture, ZXing does a great job, but to get the Camera Preview realtime, and feed it to ZXing. After a little research I found this forum https://web.archive.org/web/20150328233747/http://developer.nokia.com/community/discussion/showthread.php/247707-Windows-Phone-8-1-Windows-Media-Capture-API-and-Preview-Frames. Can someone give me a working sample of combining an MFT and ZXing? Or how can I get the preview and handle it in my C# code? 
My project is close to the deadline, so please help me out!
Right now the barcode scanning is really messy, I have a "Scan" UI button, which calls the MediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync method, but that's not a good solution. I need realtime, automatic scanning.

Thank you!

Comment: Which zxing library are you using? Most I've seen come with working samples that you can build upon.

Comment: I know they have working samples for Silverlight. But for Windows Phone 8.1 RUNTIME, their sample is very inefficient, slow, thus not suitable for realitme scanning. Their sample saves the photo to storage, than scans it. I found an improvment saving the photo to a stream, which is not bad, but still far-far away from the Windows Phone Silverlight version. In Windows Phone Silverlight you can access the camera preview very easily with PhotoCamera.GetPreviewBufferArgb32.

Comment: I finally found a solution. I Microsoft engineer, Matthieu Maitre, hacked together something very useful. The main purpose of his project was "Apply image effects from the Nokia Imaging SDK and DirectX HLSL pixel shaders to videos in Universal Store Apps..". He had an "effect" called "QrCodeDetector", which I tried out and worked, but was really slow. So I asked him if he could enhance the effect, and in two days he updated the nuget package, and it works, and it is lightning fast now: https://github.com/mmaitre314/VideoEffect#realtime-video-analysis-and-qr-code-detection

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found a solution. I Microsoft engineer, Matthieu Maitre, hacked together something very useful. The main purpose of his project was "Apply image effects from the Nokia Imaging SDK and DirectX HLSL pixel shaders to videos in Universal Store Apps..". He had an "effect" called "QrCodeDetector", which I tried out and worked, but was really slow. So I asked him if he could enhance the effect, and in two days he updated the nuget package, and it works, and it is lightning fast now: https://github.com/mmaitre314/VideoEffect#realtime-video-analysis-and-qr-code-detection

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It works. But for 2D barcodes, it's really slow and mostly incorrect. The problem is that the code in the VideoEffect example can't focus the camera. I've added some focus codes but none of them works. Could you plz help with the problem?

Comment: I think he'll update the code soon to support autofocus. On low-end devices, like the lumia 520, autofocus is not supported, so the solution is to trigger the focus in intervals, for example every 3 seconds. You should keep checking the github page to see if he updated it.

Comment: He has updated the code recently and it works great with the Focus. Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: I could be wrong but I thought that the imaging library does not support all architectures. Also, his code only seems to support QR type barcodes.

Comment: Yes, it supports arm only. But he uses zxing lib which supports 1D barcode types as well. I use it in my app, so trust me it does :)