# QR code in Universal Windows

Tags: win-universal-app, qr-code, zxing

How correct way to preview video and recognize QR (any codes with ZXing)?

In windows phone 8.1 i start preview with **MediaCapture** and with [VideoEffect](https://github.com/mmaitre314/VideoEffect) recognize QR code.

In Universal Windows VideoEffect not work.

[Recognize by timer with CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Capture-QR-code-in-Windows-f665a28d/sourcecode?fileId=132547&pathId=1686895373) is slowly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, my solution

1. Create new WinRT project "Windows Runtime Component (Universal Windows)
2. In WinRT create

```cs
class CaptureVideoEffect : IBasicVideoEffect (from Windows.Media.Effects)
```

3. Attach effect to MediaCapture

```cs
await capture.AddEffectAsync(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview, typeof(CaptureVideoEffect).FullName, ...);
```

4. Now in CaptureVideoEffect.ProcessFrame(ProcessVideoFrameContext context) you get RealTime video output
5. In CaptureVideoEffect.ProcessFrame skip frame if previous not finish decoded
6. Get image as byte[]

```cs
var frameSize = inputFrameBitmap.PixelWidth * inputFrameBitmap.PixelHeight * 4;
var frameBuffer = new Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer((uint)frameSize);
inputFrameBitmap.CopyToBuffer(frameBuffer);
byte[] bitmap = frameBuffer.ToArray();
```

7. Decode with

```cs
result = barcodeReader.Decode(bitmap, inputFrameBitmap.PixelWidth, inputFrameBitmap.PixelHeight, BitmapFormat.RGB32);

public sealed class BarcodeReader
{
     public Result Decode([ReadOnlyArray] byte[] rawRGB, int width, int height, BitmapFormat format);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right about using `MediaCapture` and `ZXing` lib, but I think it should works camera preview frame. My idea is initialize the camera, then get the preview frame and turn it to `WriteableBitmap` and at last use `Zxing` Api to analyse this `WriteableBitmap`.

Here is my sample:

```xml
 <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="4*" />
         <RowDefinition Height="*" />
         <RowDefinition Height="*" />
         <RowDefinition Height="*" />
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <CaptureElement x:Name="PreviewControl" Stretch="Uniform" Grid.Row="0" />
     <Button Content="Click Me" Click="Button_Click" Grid.Row="1" />
     <TextBlock x:Name="txtDecoderType" Grid.Row="2" />
     <TextBlock x:Name="txtDecoderContent" Grid.Row="3" />
 </Grid>
```

key point in my code here:

```cs
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;

    // Useful to know when to initialize/clean up the camera
    Application.Current.Suspending += Application_Suspending;
    Application.Current.Resuming += Application_Resuming;
}

private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _displayOrientation = _displayInformation.CurrentOrientation;
    _displayInformation.OrientationChanged += DisplayInformation_OrientationChanged;
    await InitializeCameraAsync();
    await _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.FocusAsync();
    await GetPreviewFrameAsSoftwareBitmapAsync();
}

private readonly DisplayInformation _displayInformation = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();
private DisplayOrientations _displayOrientation = DisplayOrientations.Portrait;

// Rotation metadata to apply to the preview stream (MF_MT_VIDEO_ROTATION)
// Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868174.aspx
private static readonly Guid RotationKey = new Guid("C380465D-2271-428C-9B83-ECEA3B4A85C1");

// Prevent the screen from sleeping while the camera is running
private readonly DisplayRequest _displayRequest = new DisplayRequest();

// For listening to media property changes
private readonly SystemMediaTransportControls _systemMediaControls = SystemMediaTransportControls.GetForCurrentView();

// MediaCapture and its state variables
private MediaCapture _mediaCapture;

private bool _isInitialized = false;
private bool _isPreviewing = false;

// Information about the camera device
private bool _mirroringPreview = false;

private bool _externalCamera = false;

private async void Application_Suspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
{
    // Handle global application events only if this page is active
    // See official sample 
}

private async void Application_Resuming(object sender, object o)
{
    // Handle global application events only if this page is active
    // See official sample 
}

protected override async void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    // Handling of this event is included for completenes, as it will only fire when navigating between pages and this sample only includes one page    
    // See official sample 
}

private async void SystemMediaControls_PropertyChanged(SystemMediaTransportControls sender, SystemMediaTransportControlsPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
    // See official sample 
}

private async void DisplayInformation_OrientationChanged(DisplayInformation sender, object args)
{
    // See official sample 
}

private async void MediaCapture_Failed(MediaCapture sender, MediaCaptureFailedEventArgs errorEventArgs)
{
    // See official sample 
}

private async Task InitializeCameraAsync()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("InitializeCameraAsync");

    if (_mediaCapture == null)
    {
        // Attempt to get the back camera if one is available, but use any camera device if not
        var cameraDevice = await FindCameraDeviceByPanelAsync(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Back);

        if (cameraDevice == null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("No camera device found!");
            return;
        }

        // Create MediaCapture and its settings
        _mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();

        // Register for a notification when something goes wrong
        _mediaCapture.Failed += MediaCapture_Failed;

        var settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings { VideoDeviceId = cameraDevice.Id };

        // Initialize MediaCapture
        try
        {
            await _mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(settings);
            _isInitialized = true;
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("The app was denied access to the camera");
        }

        // If initialization succeeded, start the preview
        if (_isInitialized)
        {
            // Figure out where the camera is located
            if (cameraDevice.EnclosureLocation == null || cameraDevice.EnclosureLocation.Panel == Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Unknown)
            {
                // No information on the location of the camera, assume it's an external camera, not integrated on the device
                _externalCamera = true;
            }
            else
            {
                // Camera is fixed on the device
                _externalCamera = false;

                // Only mirror the preview if the camera is on the front panel
                _mirroringPreview = (cameraDevice.EnclosureLocation.Panel == Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Front);
            }

            await StartPreviewAsync();
        }
    }
}

private async Task StartPreviewAsync()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("StartPreviewAsync");

    // Prevent the device from sleeping while the preview is running
    _displayRequest.RequestActive();

    // Register to listen for media property changes
    _systemMediaControls.PropertyChanged += SystemMediaControls_PropertyChanged;

    // Set the preview source in the UI and mirror it if necessary
    PreviewControl.Source = _mediaCapture;
    PreviewControl.FlowDirection = _mirroringPreview ? FlowDirection.RightToLeft : FlowDirection.LeftToRight;

    // Start the preview
    await _mediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
    _isPreviewing = true;

    // Initialize the preview to the current orientation
    if (_isPreviewing)
    {
        await SetPreviewRotationAsync();
    }
}

private async Task SetPreviewRotationAsync()
{
    // Only need to update the orientation if the camera is mounted on the device
    if (_externalCamera) return;

    // Calculate which way and how far to rotate the preview
    int rotationDegrees = ConvertDisplayOrientationToDegrees(_displayOrientation);

    // The rotation direction needs to be inverted if the preview is being mirrored
    if (_mirroringPreview)
    {
        rotationDegrees = (360 - rotationDegrees) % 360;
    }

    // Add rotation metadata to the preview stream to make sure the aspect ratio / dimensions match when rendering and getting preview frames
    var props = _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.GetMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview);
    props.Properties.Add(RotationKey, rotationDegrees);
    await _mediaCapture.SetEncodingPropertiesAsync(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview, props, null);
}

private async Task StopPreviewAsync()
{
    // See official sample 
}

private async Task GetPreviewFrameAsSoftwareBitmapAsync()
{
    // Get information about the preview
    var previewProperties = _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.GetMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview) as VideoEncodingProperties;

    // Create the video frame to request a SoftwareBitmap preview frame
    var videoFrame = new VideoFrame(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, (int)previewProperties.Width, (int)previewProperties.Height);

    // Capture the preview frame
    using (var currentFrame = await _mediaCapture.GetPreviewFrameAsync(videoFrame))
    {
        // Collect the resulting frame
        SoftwareBitmap previewFrame = currentFrame.SoftwareBitmap;
        WriteableBitmap wbmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)previewProperties.Width, (int)previewProperties.Height);
        previewFrame.CopyToBuffer(wbmap.PixelBuffer);
        qrcode(wbmap);
    }
}

private async Task CleanupCameraAsync()
{
    // See official sample 
}

private static async Task<DeviceInformation> FindCameraDeviceByPanelAsync(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel desiredPanel)
{
    // See official sample 
}

private static int ConvertDisplayOrientationToDegrees(DisplayOrientations orientation)
{
    // See official sample 
}

private async void qrcode(WriteableBitmap bmp)
{
    IBarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader();
    // detect and decode the barcode inside the bitmap
    var result = reader.Decode(bmp);
    // do something with the result
    if (result != null)
    {
        txtDecoderType.Text = result.BarcodeFormat.ToString();
        txtDecoderContent.Text = result.Text;
    }
    else
    {
        await GetPreviewFrameAsSoftwareBitmapAsync();
    }
}
```

I've tested this code with Lumia 950, it works quickly and fine by my side sometimes, but sometimes it just can't decode the preview frame. So it's just simple sample here, not 100% correct can be used in a formal project. What I did is trying to use `Zxing` api with the official [Camera preview frame sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraGetPreviewFrame), so if you have any problem about get preview frame, you can look into this sample. There is also a [Zxing sample for QR code](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile) here, you can also download it and have a check.

Addition: you will need to enable the `Internet(Client)`, `Microphone`, `Webcam` capabilities in the manifest file.

Comment: Can you suggest some way to handle video frame on windows phone 8.1 store apps? without `CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync` or `CapturePhotoToStreamAsync` methods.

Comment: @AndriiKrupka, I'm not sure, here is official [Video stabilization sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraVideoStabilization), there is also preview frame, so I think it's the same. But you don't want to use `CapturePhotoToStreamAsync` methods, so I don't think it is about video or photo, I just use `IBarcodeReader` of Zxing to decode `WriteableBitmap`, `WriteableBitmap` is necessary here. But I didn't go through the whole lib, maybe there is other method directly decode the preview video? Can you check the Zxing sample on GitHub in my answer?

Comment: I've found what I wanted. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28435818/implement-realtime-barcode-scanner-on-windows-phone-8-1-runtime-using-zxing-and

Comment: Scan start with Button_Click? Not in auto mode (real time)? I need real time. I post solution for preview + auto scan with ZXing in WP 8.1 and UWP 10 later.

Comment: @AlexandrSulimov, you mean by my sample? You can move the code from button click event to `OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)` method, then it will behavior like auto mode. Wait for your old sample.

Comment: I mean "all time, auto scanning, without user, any visible code". After start camera/preview - app must recognize all codes in preview.